# Match String to ABPropertyID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working now with the AddressBook and I need to convert(match) the String representation of ABPropertyID to ABPropertyID:

```
@"kABPersonEmailProperty" -> ABPropertyID kABPersonEmailProperty;
```

Can I do it flexible without using ifs?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `ABPropertyID` is defined as `int32_t`, i.e. a signed 32-bit integer. It should be easy to convert a string to the same type and compare the two.

Comment: I receive a String (e.g. @"kABPersonEmailProperty") and I should create an appropriate ABPropertyID

Comment: Hm, I have found a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247832/accessing-constants-using-key-value-coding-in-objective-c  but I don't want to use dictionaries, there is a way to make it work with KeyValueCoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do it flexible without using ifs?

Not really. The easiest way is probably to manually prepare an `NSDictionary` in code that maps between the two. There is no way to do this entirely automatically because the names of the constants are not part of the compiled program.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *mapping = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"kABPersonEmailProperty", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:kABPersonEmailProperty],
    @"kABPersonEmailProperty", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:kABPersonBirthdayProperty],
    nil];
```